# How to build and upload docker-compose file inside jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

I need to build a docker image using docker-compose.yaml file and then I need to push it on dockerhub.
I used following command to build Dockerfile and push it to dockerhub with jenkins docker plugin.

```
stage('Building image and Push') {
      steps{
        script {
          customImage = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}")
          customImage.push()
        }
      }
    }
```

Is there a similar method to write this kind of command to build and push docker-compose file?

PS: I heard about about a plugin called [Docker compose build step](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-compose-build-step/). Can I do same as above with this plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not seem supported in a scripted pipeline.

Using purely a declarative pipeline on an agent based on the [`docker-compose` image](https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose) (so with `docker-compose` preinstalled), I suppose you can shell script those commands directly:

```yaml
stage('Build Docker Image') {  
    steps{                     
    sh 'docker-compose build'     
    echo 'Docker-compose-build Build Image Completed'                
    }           
}
```

And then login to DockerHub and push, as described in "[Simple Jenkins Declarative Pipeline to Push Docker Image To Docker Hub](https://thetechdarts.com/deploy-to-dockerhub-using-jenkins-declarative-pipeline/)"

```yaml
stage('Login to Docker Hub') {          
    steps{                          
    sh 'echo $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_PSW | sudo docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_USR --password-stdin'                     
    echo 'Login Completed'      
    }           
}
```

```yaml
stage('Push Image to Docker Hub') {         
    steps{                            
 sh 'sudo docker push <dockerhubusername>/<dockerhubreponame>:$BUILD_NUMBER'           
echo 'Push Image Completed'       
    }            
}
```

A manual approach, since an "`agent docker-compose`" is not directly available (you have docker [`agent docker/dockerfile/kubernetes`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent), but no `docker-compose` option)